# Paypal Auto Renewal for Android

Tags: java, android, curl

Paypal Auto renewal for Android, it gives error invalid_client every time. This is the curl request as per their documentation on git hub :-

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -H "Authorization: Basic QWZV...==" \
 -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=EBYhRW3ncivudQn8UopLp4A28...'
```

and the authorization code response I sent is :-

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "live",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.13.1",
        "platform": "Android",
        "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },  
    "response": {
        "code": "C101.juNHfr9IkN_RoWpNxgMGkKTnEX9hG9N4BO99BYZKkovMOS4xwor1s68pS_-V4dAK.UHck5sVN1AQ2LJHwtTBJMmX_cNa"     },
    "response_type": "authorization_code"
    }
```

Using this response curl request needs to be fired. But I get invalid client every time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, basically authorization in header is merchants keys authentication.